# Using <fileSets> with Maven assemblies

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to add specific directories from Maven modules into my build. I believe that `fileSets` are the way to go back this.

I would appreciate a clear and concise way of using `fileSets` to obtain necessary directories from Maven modules that just simply contain a directory with some necessary resources.

Comment: Do you want to add files to the artifact being generated (like the Jar file)? Or move file outside jar (like license files etc)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to include entire modules, use moduleSets, but if you want to pick and choose which files to add you can use fileSets in an assembly config file from the top level project like this:

```
  <fileSets>
     <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/myModule/src/main/resources</directory>   
        <includes>
           <include>*.txt</include>
        </includes>
     </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
```

Comment: where do you place the fileSets tag in a pom ?

Comment: This goes into the [assembly descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) file.